# i want to parse only json where section is 2 two. but in responce all the json files parse

Tags: java, android, json

[this is my response i want to remove null cardviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30nwj.jpg)i want to parse only json object which have section  == 2 it works but in my recyclerview also null values prints of of array length.

```
package com.example.movies.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.movies.R;
import com.example.movies.fragments.Movies;
import com.example.movies.model.Songsapis;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




public class MoviesFragmentRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesFragmentRVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Songsapis> songsapis;
    private int drawable;
    private static ClickListener clickListener;

    public MoviesFragmentRVAdapter(Movies context, int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
        songsapis = new ArrayList<>();
    }






    @Override
    public MoviesFragmentRVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(drawable, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesFragmentRVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Context context = holder.bookImage.getContext();
        Songsapis songs = songsapis.get(position);
        if (songs.getSection().equals("2")){
            holder.bookTitle.setText(songs.getTitle());
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(songs.getThumbnail())
                    .into(holder.bookImage);

        }









    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (songsapis.size() );
    }
    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {



        private TextView bookTitle;
        private ImageView bookImage;
        CardView container;


        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            bookTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_id);
            bookImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_img_id);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_card);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);

        }
    }

    public void addAll(List<Songsapis> list) {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {


            songsapis.add(list.get(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        MoviesFragmentRVAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);

    }
}
```

and here is my json

```
  {
package: {
id: "com.latesthindisongs.app",
offline: 0,
title: "Latest Songs",
appversion: "1.0"
},
sections: [
{
id: 2,
title: "80's Songs"
},
{
id: 3,
title: "90's Songs"
}
],
listings: [
{
section: 2,
title: "Ranveer Singh NEW Hindi Movie ",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTqACYjHy5",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/FOaXXdi-8TE/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 2,
title: "Dekha Ek Khwab Song, Silsila | Amitabh | Rekha | Kishore Kumar | Lata Mangeshkar",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43wT0xhvfsA",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/43wT0xhvfsA/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 2,
title: "Pyar Ka Dard - Kishore Kumar & Asha Bhosle",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYsNBclR4nQ",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/BYsNBclR4nQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 2,
title: "Ek Roz Main Tadapkar (HD) - Bemisal Songs - Amitabh Bachchan - Rakhee Gulzar - Kishore Kumar",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvdYoPEDlKM",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/TvdYoPEDlKM/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 2,
title: "Kitni Khoobsoorat Yeh | Rakhee | Amitabh Bachchan | Bemisal | Vinod Mehra | Kishore Kumar ",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3yQJZagDTw",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/h3yQJZagDTw/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 3,
title: "Ranveer Singh NEW Hindi Movie ",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTqACYjHy5",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/FOaXXdi-8TE/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 3,
title: "Dekha Ek Khwab Song, Silsila | Amitabh | Rekha | Kishore Kumar | Lata Mangeshkar",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43wT0xhvfsA",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/43wT0xhvfsA/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 3,
title: "Tu Is Tarah male Aap To Aise Na",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoZukqIx8q4",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/Sa3u73QJ4bk/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 3,
title: "Pyar Ka Dard - Kishore Kumar & Asha Bhosle",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYsNBclR4nQ",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/BYsNBclR4nQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
},
{
section: 3,
title: "Ek Roz Main Tadapkar (HD) - Bemisal Songs - Amitabh Bachchan - Rakhee Gulzar - Kishore Kumar",
url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvdYoPEDlKM",
thumbnail: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/TvdYoPEDlKM/maxresdefault.jpg",
type: "video"
}
]
}
```

in my ui view i get the records of json where section == 2 . which are 5 records but after these i also get 5 cardview in my recyclview which are null

Comment: Filter the list before passing that to the adapter or notifying the adapter.

Comment: i dont know how to do that plz help me. i am a student

Comment: @Waseem first create a list of objects that have section2 and then pass the list to adapter

Comment: @HardikChauhan will you plz?

Comment: loop through your list, check the section, and add section 2 elements to another list, then use this *another list* in your RecyclerView

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko bro i am not a professional i am a student plz give a piece of code how to do that?

Comment: it doesn't work this way, we are not here to do the job instead of you. Please be more specific, what exactly is a problem for you to do what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,
This is very basic solution,

```
  ArrayList<Songsapis> list = new ArrayList<Songsapis>();
for(Songsapis s: YOUR_LIST){
    if(s.getSection.equals("2")){
        list.add(s);
    }
}
```

This will create a new list with only objects having section as 2.
pass this list to your adapter.

Note - you might need to change a code little bit.